# fade in a div-bar as background for my header when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been researching and found some things to the topic but nothing was usable in my situation and often to hard for me to implement.

I'd like to get a div to fade in when you begin to scroll on my homepage. It should blend in behind my header where i got my logo as a fixed div.

"John Polo"(The header logo) is fixed on top and should get its background div faded in when scrolling, I'm trying to give you an idea with these 2 pictures :)

When opening webpage (top)
[image: when opening webpage (top)]

When you begin to scroll
[image: when you begin to scroll]

Comment: Show your code or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your question

Comment: Can you post some of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
jQuery(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of element */
    jQuery('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var logo = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
        var position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        /* fade out */
        if( position > logo  ){

            jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},500);

        }else{ jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);}

    }); 

});
```

Comment: nice that works :) just one tiny thing :D

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
jQuery(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of element */
    jQuery('.logoscrollbg').each( function(i){

        var logo = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
        var position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        /* fade out */
        if( position > logo  ){

            jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},200);

        }else{ jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},200);}

    }); 

});

When i open the page the background is visible :/ though it all works after the first scroll